# Issue with Output from DOMDocument

Tags: php

I'm using `DOMDocument` to find and strip out some HTML elements I don't want in the PHP variable `$table_data_for_db`. The raw version of `$table_data_for_db` comes with some HTML tags I don't want.  So, I'm using the code below to get rid of some tags (and the content in those tags), then saving the remaining HTML to my DB.

Here's the code I'm using to create `$table_data_for_db`...

```
    $table_data_for_db = $_POST['table_data'];

    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($table_data_for_db);
    $xPath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $nodes = $xPath->query('//*[@id="problem_header"]');
    if($nodes->item(0)) {
        $nodes->item(0)->parentNode->removeChild($nodes->item(0));
    }
    $nodes = $xPath->query('//*[@id="border_row"]');
    if($nodes->item(0)) {
        $nodes->item(0)->parentNode->removeChild($nodes->item(0));
    }
    $nodes = $xPath->query('//*[@id="fraction_class"]');
    if($nodes->item(0)) {
        $nodes->item(0)->parentNode->removeChild($nodes->item(0));
    }

    $table_data_for_db = $dom->saveHTML();
```

The problem is that I'm getting output like this...
    
    
    
       
       More of the same...

Where the `<!DOCTYPE html...`, `<html><head>` and `</head></html>` are undesirable.

I currently have a solution in place where I use `str_replace` to get rid of the undesirables before inserting into the DB, but that feels like a hack.  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why did you delete your other post? If you wanted to change your question, just use the edit function. Anyhow my answer to your other one is as follows:

It is the saveHTML function that is putting in the extra code. To make sure it does not put it in, use this for your loadHTML function:

```
$dom->loadHTML($table_data_for_db, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
```

According to http://php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php you will need at least versions: PHP 5.4 and Libxml 2.7.8

Comment: I didn't see that it had any answers.  Sorry.  I'll try this and update.

Comment: I just got `Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in /path/to/my/script.php on line 19`

Comment: Yes, I was just posting your answer when you deleted the question. It is discouraging to people trying to help you when you delete a question.

Comment: The original question seemed to change substantially enough that it warranted a new question.

Comment: I think you need at least the following versions: PHP 5.4 and Libxml 2.6. Do you know what versions you have?

Comment: My php version is 5.2.17 and the libxml is 2.7.6.

Comment: Actually, you may need 2.7.8. You can see the requirements here: http://php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php

Comment: Are you able to upgrade your software?

Comment: I'm on shared hosting, so I'm not sure.  I'm just going to go forward with my "hack" at this point and see how it goes.  I'm going to mark this as the solution though on the assumption that it will work for people who meet the requirements above. Thanks for your help.